# How to use Java applet for RTSP live streaming?

Tags: java, applet, rtsp

I need to embed RTSP live streaming in an applet.

I have already tried by using a third party API, but it is copyrighted.

I request help on how to implement RTSP protocol using Java Applet.

Comment: The best way to get help with these kind of questions is to provide what you have tried so far. Do you have any code with a specific problem?

Comment: I also fixed some grammar with your question and added appropriate tags, but please add some code or elaborate around your problem a bit more.